# When I type on SSH, the letters show up slowly

Tags: bash, ssh

Right now I'm using wi-fi at a cafe. When I type commands on my local machine in bash, it shows up at the rate I'm typing.

However, when I type commands on an ssh account, it shows up very slowly... there is a noticeable delay between when I press a key and when it appears on the screen.

Why is this? Do keystrokes in ssh only appear after they are echoed back by the server?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this? Do keystrokes in ssh only appear after they are echoed back by the server?

Yup.
If you use putty, you can try to enable "local echo".